# merge data rows if they have sequential time intervals within a specified time period

Tags: r, merge, intervals, gaps-and-islands

I have a dataset for patient medications with Start.Date and Stop.Date. Each is represented in a row. I would like to merge rows that represent the same medication given consequentially but only if the Start.Date for the later interval is within 30 days from the stop date of the earlier interval (or any number of days apart that I choose to specify). Suppose you have the dataframe below

```
 ID = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5) 
    Medication = c("aspirin", "aspirin", "aspirin", "tylenol", "lipitor", "advil") 
    Start.Date = c("05/01/2017", "05/30/2017", "07/15/2017", "05/01/2017", "05/06/2017", "05/28/2017")
Stop.Date = c("05/04/2017", "06/10/2017", "07/27/2017", "05/15/2017", "05/12/2017", "06/13/2017")
    df = data.frame(ID, Medication, Start.Date, Stop.Date) 


  ID Medication Start.Date  Stop.Date
   2    aspirin 05/01/2017 05/04/2017
   2    aspirin 05/30/2017 06/10/2017
   2    aspirin 07/15/2017 07/27/2017
   2    tylenol 05/01/2017 05/15/2017
   3    lipitor 05/06/2017 05/12/2017
   5      advil 05/28/2017 06/13/2017
```

I would like to reduce rows by ID and medication if the Stop.Date for one is within the specified 30 days after the next Start.Date. The new Start.Date and Stop.Date would encompass the time interval of both medications and the 30day or less gap between them. It should look like below:

```
ID Medication Start.Date  Stop.Date
   2    aspirin 05/01/2017 06/10/2017
   2    aspirin 07/15/2017 07/27/2017
   2    tylenol 05/01/2017 05/15/2017
   3    lipitor 05/06/2017 05/12/2017
   5      advil 05/28/2017 06/13/2017
```

Comment: please try select an answer as correct(out of all answers) so that we could close the thread completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your days to date format, so you can calculate intervals:

```
df$Start.Date <- as.Date(df$Start.Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
df$Stop.Date <- as.Date(df$Stop.Date, '%m/%d/%Y')

> df$Stop.Date - df$Start.Date
Time differences in days
[1]  3 11 12 14  6 16
```

To calculate the difference between a stop date and the next start date:

```
c(Inf, df[-1,'Start.Date'] - df[-nrow(df),'Stop.Date'])
```

The use of c(SOMETHING,...) is to keep the same length, because the first date don't have an interval. Order your data first to ensure that you have your dates in sequence:

```
df <- df[order(df$ID, df$Medication, df$Start.Date), ]
```

Now calculate the intervals for each patient and medication. It can be handily done using dplyr or data.table:

```
# Using dplyr:
library(dplyr)
df %<>% group_by(ID, Medication) %>% mutate(interval = c(Inf, Start.Date[-1] - Stop.Date[-n()]))

# Using data.table:
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, interval := c(Inf, Start.Date[-1] - Stop.Date[-.N]), by = .(ID, Medication)]
```

Update Stop.Date for rows before intervals with 30 days or less:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) if(df$interval[i]<=30) df$Stop.Date[i-1] <- df$Stop.Date[i]
```

Lastly, exclude the rows with interval <= 30 and the column interval:

```
# If you're using dplyr:
df %<>% filter(!interval<=30) %>% select(-interval)

# If you're using data.table:
df <- df[!interval<=30, ]; df[, interval := NULL]

> df
   ID Medication Start.Date  Stop.Date
1:  2    aspirin 2017-05-01 2017-06-10
2:  2    aspirin 2017-07-15 2017-07-27
3:  2    tylenol 2017-05-01 2017-05-15
4:  3    lipitor 2017-05-06 2017-05-12
5:  5      advil 2017-05-28 2017-06-13
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not reliable/ reproducible. Try, for instance, to change the year on row 2 of the original df to 2014 (instead of 2017) and you will get an erroneous outcome where start date is earlier than stop date. What is the dplyr solution (I am more comfortable. familiar with dplyr but can't seem to figure this out)

Comment: @gfa2001 If you understand what the code is doing, should be relatively easy to increment. If your dates aren't in sequence, just order your data.frame. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I figured I should arrange first. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested to collapse medication periods if there is a gap of not more than 30 days between the end of one period and the start of the next period.

The solution below requires that medication periods for the same individual and the same medication never do overlap which is a sensible assumption (and is checked for).

#### 1. `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
min_gap <- 30
df %>%
  # convert date strings to class Date
  mutate_at(c("Start.Date", "Stop.Date"), lubridate::mdy) %>%
  arrange(ID, Medication, Start.Date) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Medication) %T>%
  # medication periods must not overlap for ID and Medication
  {summarize(., tmp = all(Start.Date >= lag(Stop.Date, default = Start.Date[1] - 1))) %$% 
      stopifnot(all(tmp))} %>% 
  # count non-subsequent medication periods, i.e., with gaps of at least min_gap days
  mutate(Medic.Period = cumsum(Start.Date > lag(Stop.Date, default = Start.Date[1]) + min_gap)) %>%
  # determine start and stop dates for each collapsed period
  group_by(ID, Medication, Medic.Period) %>%
  summarise(Start.Date = first(Start.Date), Stop.Date = last(Stop.Date))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 5
> # Groups:   ID, Medication [?]
>      ID Medication Medic.Period Start.Date Stop.Date 
>   <dbl> <fct>             <int> <date>     <date>    
> 1     2 aspirin               0 2017-05-01 2017-06-10
> 2     2 aspirin               1 2017-07-15 2017-07-27
> 3     2 tylenol               0 2017-05-01 2017-05-15
> 4     3 lipitor               0 2017-05-06 2017-05-12
> 5     5 advil                 0 2017-05-28 2017-06-13
> ```

The `cumsum()` function is used to increment the medication period counter whenever a new period is encountered, i.e., with a gap of more than 30 days between stop of the previous period and start of the actual period.

#### 2. `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
min_gap <- 30
# coerce date strings to class Date
cols <- stringr::str_subset(names(df), "Date$")
setDT(df)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, lubridate::mdy), .SDcols = cols][
  # create medication counters for each ID and Medication
  order(Start.Date), 
   Medic.Period := {
     tmp <- shift(Stop.Date, fill = Start.Date[1] - 1)
     stopifnot(all(Start.Date > tmp))
     cumsum(Start.Date > tmp + min_gap)
   }, 
   by = .(ID, Medication)][
     # aggregate to find the overal start and stop dates for each medication period
     , .(Start.Date = min(Start.Date), Stop.Date = max(Stop.Date)), 
     by = .(ID, Medication, Medic.Period)]
```

> ```
>    ID Medication Medic.Period Start.Date  Stop.Date
> 1:  2    aspirin            0 2017-05-01 2017-06-10
> 2:  2    aspirin            1 2017-07-15 2017-07-27
> 3:  2    tylenol            0 2017-05-01 2017-05-15
> 4:  3    lipitor            0 2017-05-06 2017-05-12
> 5:  5      advil            0 2017-05-28 2017-06-13
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
df$date_diff <- as.Date(as.character(df$Stop.Date), format="%m/%d/%Y")-as.Date(as.character(df$Start.Date), format="%m/%d/%Y")
ind <- apply( df[5] , 1 , function(x) any( x < 30 ) )
df[ ind , ]
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder. No this does not answer my question. I made edits to my question so it is more clear